# Add/ Remove Control object from a Form class using another class C# WinForms

Tags: null, user-controls, parent

I have this function

```
private void UndockControl()
    {
        if (Parent == null)
        {
            Control c = this.Parent;
        }
        if (m_floatingFrame == null)
        {
            m_floatingFrame = new FloatingFrameWindow();
            m_floatingFrame.Owner = ParentForm;
        }

        if (Parent is TableLayoutPanel)
        {
            var parentPanel = (TableLayoutPanel)Parent;
            var col = parentPanel.GetColumn(this);
            var small = new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 1);
            parentPanel.ColumnStyles[col] = small;
        }

        Parent.Controls.Remove(this);
        m_floatingFrame.Controls.Add(this);
        ParentForm.FormClosing += ParentForm_FormClosing;
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        m_floatingFrame.Show();
        m_isDocked = false;
        uiDockButton.ImageIndex = 0;
    }
```

This control is nested in other control.
If I make the function public and make an instance of that class to call this function, when I run the code will give me an error in this line `Parent.Controls.Remove(this);` because Parent object is null (also ParentForm).
Is there a way to instance or something in order to have the parent control for this control?
The code above works fine if I use an event button to call the function (internal event, not from other classes (forms)).

Answer (score 0):

I did a small project in order  to find out the behaviour of control nested in other controls and called outside of the form class. It seems that if it is called from another class the parent form will be null.